# how to use find text as variable in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have variables in file1.pm file 
    file1.pm

```
package oa;
use strict;
use warnings;
our $first1= 'DTH';
1;
```

Now want access this variable within variable, this is my main program but I did’t get output i know problem is "oa:$var"
Can i use “/oa::$var/ “ like this to access variable?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use file1;
$input='DTH';
$var=first . 1;
if($input =~ /oa::$var/){
print “DTH”;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Perl is not PHP, and the `$` sigil comes in front of the package name: If you want to access a package variable, then do `$PackageName::var_name`.

`./MyPackage.pm`:

```
package MyPackage;  # package names should be CamelCase!
use strict;
use warnings;

our $first1 = 'DHT';
1;
```

`./script.pl`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MyPackage;

my $input = 'DHT';
if ($input =~ /$MyPackage::first1/) {
    print "DHT\n";
}
```

However, you are also refering to a variable by name. This is a bad thing to do, and makes it almost impossible to understand and maintain such a program. You can use *hashes* instead (also known as associative arrays, maps, or dictionaries):

In `MyPackage`:

```
our %stuff = (
    first1 => 'DHT',
    other1 => 'foobar',
);
```

In the script:

```
my $var = 'first1';
if ($input =~ /$MyPackage::stuff{$var}/) {
    ...
```

Comment: can i declare like this "use D:/myfiles/MyPackage"

Comment: @Kathir.K No, the `use` operator takes a package name, then searches for the file itself. But you can add new search locations via `use lib 'D:/myfiles/'`, after which `use MyPackage` would find `D:/myfiles/MyPackage.pm` ← the `.pm` extension is important. Alternatively, you can load a file manually: `BEGIN{ require 'D:/some/path'; MyPackage->import }`. The `require` can load any filename. The `->import` call on the package name (not the file name) is important to ensure correct initialization. The surrounding `BEGIN { … }` makes all of this happen during compile time, just like `use` works.

Comment: Why i cant print text in mydatabase i used like this print "$MyPackage::stuff{$var}"; but won't work.